# How do I split the getActionCommand() in order to get the first element in the string?

Tags: java, swing, split

I have a groups of `JRadioButton` in my program.

```
public class SalePanel extends JPanel  implements View { 
    private JTextField sell = new JTextField(5);
    private ButtonGroup buttons = new ButtonGroup();
    private Stadium stadium;
```

I added buttons here:

```
private void build(Stadium stadium){
    add(buttonBox(stadium));
}
```

This is how I create a button:

```
private Box buttonBox(Stadium stadium)
{   Box box = Box.createVerticalBox();
    SaleListener listener = new SaleListener();
    for (Group group: stadium.groups()) {
        box.add(button(group, listener));

    }
    return box;
}   


private JRadioButton button(Group group, SaleListener listener){
    JRadioButton button  = new JRadioButton();
    button.addActionListener(listener);
    buttons.add(button);
    button.add(Box.createHorizontalStrut(35));
    button.add(new JLabel(group.name() + " @ $"+ formatted(group.price())));
    return button;  
}
```

The label of the button is here: `button.add(new JLabel(group.name()` <--- this is the label which is in another class and has a name like "Front", "Middle" or whatever.

My task now is:

1. To pick up the radio button label from the event (I use `getActionCommand()` to get the label)
2. Get the group name from the label (I need to split the string on a space, and get the first string in the returned array).
3. Find the group from the name:
   lookup the group given the name

**So**, I am doing it the following way:

```
private class SaleListener implements ActionListener { 
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) { 

        String[] words = e.getActionCommand().split(" ");
        String groupName  = words[0];
        for (Group group: stadium.groups()) {
            if (group.matches(groupName)){
                group.sell(sale());
                update();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, it is not working, and I can't find where mistake is. 
Could you please give my any advice about this task? What am I doing wrong?

p.s. this line of code `String[] words = e.getActionCommand().split(" ");` is not doing what I want. I tried to `System.out.println(words[0])` and it's empty, but there should be the name of the group :(

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete Verifiable Example) or [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/) (Short, Self Contained, Correct Example).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This...

```
button.add(new JLabel(group.name() + " @ $"+ formatted(group.price())));
```

Doesn't make sense.  You should be using...

```
button.setText(group.name() + " @ $"+ formatted(group.price()));
```

And...

```
button.setActionCommand(group.name());
```

If you don't care about the rest of the text...

Comment: Wow! Thanks a lot. This line helped: `button.setActionCommand(group.name());`
I appreciate it!

p.s. 
`button.add(new JLabel(group.name() + " @ $"+ formatted(group.price())));` - in my program it does make sense :) I add the label to the button and it works!

Comment: But `JRadioButton` already has a label, which supports mnemonic (keyboard short cuts), so no, it doesn't makes sense generally